# Get user information from Auth0 using ASP.NET MVC 6 WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, auth0

I am using JwtBearerAuthentication in my WebAPI (ASP.NET Core RC1) to authenticate (Auth0) users accessing my API. In Startup.cs I configure the connection to Auth0 using the following code. What am I missing to access user information about each user accessing the API?

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
                options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
                options.Audience = clientId;
                options.Authority = domain;

                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnValidatedToken = context =>
                    {
                        var claimsIdentity = context.AuthenticationTicket.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token",
                            context.Request.Headers["Authorization"][0].Substring(context.AuthenticationTicket.AuthenticationScheme.Length + 1)));
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                };
            });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all apologies that the sample I am giving you is in RC2. I do not have RC1 on my computer and installing it after I have installed RC2 is not a risk I want to take. If you cannot for some reason upgrade to RC2, then hopefully you can retrofit this sample to RC1.

OK, so first of it is important to understand that the information you can retrieve about the user is going to be limited to what is contained in the JWT. So be sure to set the correct scopes when requesting the token. So for example, if you want the name and email address of the user, be sure to set `scope` to `openid name email`.

Alright so if you want to access the information inside the `OnTokenValidated` event, then you can use the following code:

```
var options = new JwtBearerOptions
{
    Audience = Configuration["auth0:clientId"],
    Authority = $"https://{Configuration["auth0:domain"]}/",
    Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            // If you need the user's information for any reason at this point, you can get it by looking at the Claims property
            // of context.Ticket.Principal.Identity
            var claimsIdentity = context.Ticket.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (claimsIdentity != null)
            {
                // Get the user's ID
                string userId = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                // Get the name
                string name = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "name")?.Value;
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
};
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);
```

If you want to access the information from inside a controller action, you can simply look at the claims of the `User`, e.g.

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("userinfo")]
    public object UserInformation()
    {
        string userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

        // Get the name
        string name = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "name")?.Value;

        return new
        {
            UserId = userId,
            Name = name
        };
    }
}
```

If you need to access more information about the user, you can also use our full .NET SDK for the Management API and use the user related methods to retrieve more user information. My suggestion however would be to rather ensure you set the correct scopes when the token is issued and ensure they are contained in the JWT token.

The complete sample is available at https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-aspnetcore-webapi-samples/tree/master/Samples/user-info

Comment: SO is limiting the amount of links I can post. You can get more info on scopes at https://auth0.com/docs/scopes

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer :) I will try it out and get back to you about my progress.